# Creating reports with PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, report, reporting

I am curious what the best route is to go when dealing with reports in PHP.

I dislike Java, and I really don't want to install anything extra on the server. Is there a possibility?

The type of report I want to create:
A report that has header with a logo, grouping of information, tally totals.

I am not sure if this is possible without installing anything but any response would be much appreciated.

I'm not sure the best route to go. I did create an XML->PDF, but it wouldn't be as flexible as I would like it to be for reports.

Comment: Who voted for closure, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), which is the PHP class that allows you to create PDF files with pretty high flexibility.

You do not need to install anything new to use FPDF - just look at their tutorial on their page.

Answer (score 2):

I use [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) for quite a while, it's fantastic fro what I need to do and handles a lot of XHTML elements which makes life easy to port it to a pdf format. It's not really an installation, just deploying the files you need and run the tcpdf class to generate what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Without installing anything on the server, you're sort of handicapped, unless you want to adapt your reports to just generate printable HTML (which isn't a bad option).

If you can install something though, [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is a good option and should let you render PDFs fairly consistently.

Answer (score -1):

Today i tried to make my first app with http://www.livedocx.com/ it's amazing.